# Log of the Gaussian data likelihood

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

Given that the model distributon is Gaussian with known variance $\sigma^2 = 1$

$$
p(x_i | \mu, \sigma^2=1) = \mathcal{N}(x_i | \mu, 1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{-\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2}}
,$$

the log of the data likelihood $\mathcal{D} = \{x_0,x_1,\dots, x_n \}$ can be expressed as function of $\mu$ as following:
$$
\ln{p(D|\mu)} = -\frac{1}{2}\Big(- 2\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\mu  + N\mu^2 \Big) + \text{const}$$

where $\text{const}$ utilizes all of the term which do not depend on $\mu$.

How do we formally prove this equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\log p(D \mid \mu)
&= \log \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i \mid \mu)
\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \log p(x_i \mid \mu)
\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(-\frac{1}{2} \log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2} (x_i - \mu)^2\right)\\
&= \text{const} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2
\\
&= \text{const} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 - 2 x_i \mu + \mu^2)
\\
&= \text{const} - \frac{1}{2} \left(n\mu^2 - 2 \mu\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)
\end{align}